# laravel 4 docx file validation not working

Tags: php, file, validation, laravel-4

I gave the validation rule like this

```
'file'=>'mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,docx|max:1024'
```

But when the `docx` file is uploaded, it shows this error

```
The file must be a file of type: png, gif, jpeg, txt, pdf, doc, docx.
```

Other types are working. I have tested it with doc and images and PDF. What do I have to do to solve this? I have tried creating `mimes.php` in the app/config folder but didn't work. I'm using laravel 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a docx is actually a zipped XML file format. It thinks you're uploading a zip file.

> Office Open XML is a zipped, XML-based file format... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)

You can get around this by allowing a zip to be uploaded and validate it ends in .docx otherwise it will delete the file and throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

I did have that issue, and I solved it through these mime type:

```
$mimeType = array('application/zip','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/vnd.ms-office','application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

instead of using just doc/docx use above mimes, and you won't get validation error, when uploading doc/docx files.

Validation related to mime type:

```
if (!in_array($file->getMimeType(), $this->mimeType)) {
    $this->errors->add($key, $this->messages['mimeType']);
}
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: you mean i should give it like this `'file'=>'mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,application/zip','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/vnd.ms-office','application/vnd.ms-excel|max:1024'`  ??

Comment: yeah, if that works, what I did was little different I upload a file and then I use to take the mime type of the uploaded file and have a match with these defined mimes, If they don't match then I used to show an error. I have edited my answer to show how I used to validate.